# Use Symfony 4.4.23 without a Database, Symfony update is causing issues with this

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony4

I have an old Symfony website which is using the framework bundle but no database is required for the content. This works fine till 4.4.18 but upgrading to the latest version is giving the following error:

```
An exception occurred in driver: could not find driver
```

I haven't modified DATABASE_URL in .env or configured the driver in config/packages/doctrine.yaml. Is there anyway I can simple disable the use of database?

Comment: Is the doctrine migrations bundle installed?  If so then remove it.  The migrations bundle in conjunction with the profiler bundle recently started to spew errors if no database was connected.  Quite annoying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comment from @cerad, removing doctrine-migrations package from composer.json helped with the issue.
As I am not using a Database for the site, this is fine for me.

Answer (score -1):

if your app doesn't use the database the best course of action is to remove the `doctrine/doctrine-bundle` and/or `symfony/orm-pack` (if you've installed the orm support via pack)

if that's not an option than set the `DATABASE_URL=` to nothing (like that, not the empty string), or if you've hit some bug in dbal dsn parsing give it the dummy sqlite until the issue gets resolved `DATABASE_URL="sqlite:///%kernel.project_dir%/var/data.db"`

Comment: I removed orm-pack earlier and also removed all doctrine packages from composer.json but that didn't help. 
I didn't try the .env DATABASE_URL solution, the reply from @cerad did what I needed.

Comment: @umair if the cerad's comment hellped you have missed that doctrine/migrations dependency :)

Comment: Thank you, the dependency was loaded in composer.json and removing the package actually helped with the error